# An equilateral triangle has sides of length 8cm. A circle passes through each vertex of the triangle. Find an expression for the circumference.

Tags: geometry, circles

The equilateral triangle PQR has sides of length 8cm. A circle, centre O, passes through each of the vertices of the triangle. Find an expression for the circumference of circle.

I thought about breaking it up into sectors but I don’t know the radius.

I thought about perpendicular bisectors meeting in centre but that wouldn’t help me know the radius.

Grateful for help!

Comment: Do you know that the perpendicular bisector and the angle bisector are the same thing in an equilateral triangle?

Comment: Hint: Think of the inscribed angle theorem and what that means for the angle being formed at the center.

Comment: If you want the measure of the radius of the circle use this formula: $R=\frac{abc}{4S}$ , where R is radius and S is the area of triangle, in your case a=b=c= 5 cm.First find S.

Answer (score 2):

First, draw $\triangle\mathit{PQR}$. The angles between each side are all $60$ degrees. The center of the circle, $O$, is exactly at the center of the triangle. Then, connect each vertex of the triangle to $O$. These segments are all $r$, the radius of the circle. Next, choose a side and draw the perpendicular bisector of the side between said side and $O$.

To make that easier to understand, I'll provide an example. Let's use segment $\mathit{PQ}$. Define the midpoint of $\mathit{PQ}$ as $M$. Segment $\mathit{MO}$ is the perpendicular bisector between $\mathit{PQ}$ and $O$.

Segments $\mathit{PM}$, $\mathit{MO}$, and $\mathit{MP}$ form a 30/60/90 triangle which relates the side length of the triangle to the radius of the circle.

Let's call the side length of the circle $s$. The length of segment $\mathit{PM}$ equals $\frac{s}{2}$ and $\angle \mathit{OPM}$ is $30$ degrees. Therefore, $\cos \angle \mathit{OPM} = \cos \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{\mathit{PM}}{\mathit{OP}} = \frac{s}{2r}$. Rewriting, we get that:
$$
r = \frac{1}{2} s \sec \frac{\pi}{6}
$$

The circumference of a circle is:

$$
C = 2\pi r
$$

Substituting $r$, we get:

$$
\boxed{C = \pi s \sec \frac{\pi}{6}}
$$

This equation directly relates the side length of the triangle to the circumference of the circle.

*In order to better understand the derivation, I drew [this diagram](https://ibb.co/wNQ1CM7).*

In the context of your problem, you were meant to find an *expression* for the circumference of the circle with the side length of the triangle being $8\text{cm}$. That expression would be:

$$
\boxed{8\text{cm} \cdot \pi \sec \frac{\pi}{6}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

A circle that passes through the triangle's vertices is known as its circumcircle, and its radius is known as its circumradius $r_c$.  The circumference is obviously $2\pi r_c$.  The formula for the circumradius of a triangle with side lengths $a$, $b$, and $c$ is shown below:
[image]

Since it's an equilateral triangle, $a = b = c$.

Comment: I can include the derivation of this formula if you want.

Comment: For an equilateral triangle with side length $s$ the formula simplifies to: $\frac{s^3}{\sqrt{3s(s)(s)(s)}} = \frac{s^3}{\sqrt{3s^4}}$.

Comment: So the length of the circumference is $2\pi(\frac{512}{110.85}) \approx 2\pi(4.6188) \approx 29cm$.